# Android API for Setting QCI value to make a VoLTE Call in Android phones

Tags: android, lte

To make a VoLTE call in Android phones we have to Set QCI value as 1 (related to LTE).
Are there any APIs provided by Android Application frameworks to set this QCI value ??
I found few APIs in Android Telephony Manager, but using this i am able to check only whether access network is LTE or not, but I did not find any APIs to set QCI value. Please help to proceed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The QCI value will be assigned by the network not by the terminal.
When you open a bearer you must have the settings in the terminal ==> Volte settings (e.g. APN). SO you must first get a terminal which supports Volte and is configured properly for a particular Volte netowrk (IMS settings). Then you should be able to do calls "normally" with Android and the terminal will do the rest for you. The QCI 1 is then assigned to the bearer as it is a Volte.

Why would you need to set a particualr QCI in an app?

Comment: The network assigns radio bearers with TFTs (Traffic Flow Templates). For example, VoLTE-enabled network will assign the UE with a QCI1 bearer for all packets matching the expected template (RTP ports, UDP transport type, etc.). 
The matching of an IP packet and the assigned bearers is handled by Android, but if you are developing an application that requires specific network QoS, you must be aware of the TFTs

Answer (score 0):

QCI values will be assigned by the LTE/EPC network. QCI 5 is used for IMS signalling purpose, where dedicated bearer(QCI 1) is established for dedicated VoLTE call. In a precondition call if network determine a 183/INVITE from MT side, it start creating dedicated bearer and notify the MO. After receiving this notification, MO sends UPDATE as network resource is already reserved for this VoLTE call.